# Replace specific JSON values in random hierarchy

Tags: java, json, gson

I have plenty of various format JSON files, where I need to replace just few same elements/objects in their hierarchy. Sadly, this hierarchy is different in case of different JSON files and I unable to use predefined/hardcoded hierarchy. In some cases I have more than hundred of different variants.

Those elements could have different parent elements or level of depth, but I easy able to find them via eg.:

```
JsonObject obj = allJsonData.getAsJsonObject(objectName);
```

And value, with which I need to replace this object, I take from another JSON data and easy can get it as eg. JsonObject as well. Just sadly JsonObject don't have something like getParentObject method to get its parent and then to delete it and to add new JsonObject from another JSON data. But maybe exist other solution. I am pretty new on JSON.

Comment: It would be really useful if you could add some practical examples of what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I didn't found in GSON library corresponding way to do this, but maybe I missed something as I never before worked with JSON and decided to ask question here. I searching for corresponding method/way, something like  rootJsonObject::replace(name, JsonObject) would be great. Like existing method rootJsonObject::getAsJsonObject returns specific JsonObject data, just in my case I need to replace it with another JsonObject, to purge previous data and to put in same hierarchy place its JSON data. In my case, hierarchy can vary and subject to change, but specific fields available anyway somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on GSON library source code, I've found that **JsonObject::add** method does what I need. It works with Key/Value collection and updating in this way values, like regular dictionary functionality. Just this method name is a bit misleading as called as **add**.

To change specific JSON part/object in any hierarchy enough:

```
JsonObject rootJsonObject = ...; // JSON object which has all JSON data
JsonObject sourceJsonObject = ...; // JSON object with which I needed to replace specific JSON node
String name = ...; // name of JsonObject which I needed to replace

rootJsonObject.add(name, sourceJsonObject);
```

And it set it instead of previous value.